# Witcher 3 New Game + option is greyed out

Tags: xbox-one, the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

I just finished the main storyline in Witcher 3 on my Xbox One. Then I purchased the DLC pass that has both Hearts of Stone and Blood and Wine. I loaded my game from after completing the story line. I created a new saved game. Then I exited to the main menu. Tried to start a New Game, but everything except for `Fresh Start` is greyed out. `New Game +` is greyed out, along with `Hearts of Stone Only` and `Blood and Wine Only`. I want to start a `New Game +` so I can continue playing with my current character.

Any ideas how to enable the `New Game +` option so that I can play my DLC?

Comment: Which DLC do you have **installed**? (Not just *purchased*; New Game+ is a free DLC)

Comment: Were you perchance already playing a New Game+, from which you created the new saved game?

Comment: @Chronocidal Ok, maybe that's it. I'll go check that it has actually downloaded the DLC as well.

Comment: @Joachim No, the game I was already playing was not a New Game+.

Comment: @Chronocidal That was the problem. I purchased the DLC but it wasn't installed yet. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt* does not come with New Game+ by default.  It is one of several free DLC available for the game.

Combined with *Hearts of Stone* and *Blood and Wine* also not being available, you should check which DLC you have **installed**, not just the ones that you have **purchased**.